# BFS Maximize Minimum Distance from a Monster along a path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

A player begins on a 2d grid of size n*m. 'E' refers to the end position the the player is trying to get to, 'S' represents the start position and 'X' refers to a monster. There can be multiple monsters in the grid. The goal is to reach the end cell using a  path that maximizes the minimum distance from any monster along that path.

The code below works for some test cases but doesnt give the correct answer for many others.

```
def findBestPath(n, m, startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn, monsterRow, monsterColumn):
    # n is the number of rows, m is the number of columns
    # expand in shells starting from the monster locations
    d = [[None]*m for i in range(n)]
    # set of current location and set of next locations
    curr = set(zip(monsterRow, monsterColumn))
    deck = set()
    dist = 0
    while curr:
        for r, c in curr:
            d[r][c] = dist
        for r, c in curr:
            for dr, dc in ((0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)):
                nr, nc = r + dr, c + dc
                if 0 <= nr < n and 0 <= nc < m:
                    if d[nr][nc] is None:
                        deck.add((nr, nc))
        curr = deck
        deck = set()
        dist += 1
    # Now do a kind of modified floodfill from the start point.
    # It could be bidirectional but we are lazy.
    # Track three shells: current high-d, on-deck high-d, successor lower-d.
    visited = [[False]*m for i in range(n)]
    target = (endRow, endColumn)
    curr = {(startRow, startColumn)}
    mindist = d[startRow][startColumn]
    deck = set()
    succ = set()
    while mindist >= 0:
        while curr:
            for r, c in curr:
                if (r, c) == target:
                    return mindist
                visited[r][c] = 1
            for r, c in curr:
                for dr, dc in ((0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)):
                    nr, nc = r + dr, c + dc
                    if 0 <= nr < n and 0 <= nc < m:
                        if not visited[nr][nc]:
                            np = (nr, nc)
                            dist = d[nr][nc]
                            if dist >= mindist:
                                deck.add(np)
                            elif dist == mindist - 1:
                                succ.add(np)
            curr = deck
            deck = set()
        mindist -= 1
        curr = succ
        deck = set()
        succ = set()

print(findBestPath(5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 3, {0,0,3},{3,4,4})) // list of row positions, list of column positions for monsters
```

Ex: S = (0,0), e = (3,3), X = ((0,3), (1,2)), ans = 2

For the test case in the code, it returns 2 for findBestPath(5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 3, {0,0,3},{3,4,4}) and also returns 2 for this findBestPath(5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 3, {0,0,3},{3,4,3}) which is wrong

Comment: For this small input, it should be very easy to print the full state of the program at each step of the flood fill, and eyeball where it goes wrong.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yes but I'm looking for what's wrong in the logic of my code as there are many other larger test cases as well (which I dont have access to).

Comment: In order to see what is wrong in the logic you want to see a specific example of a wrong decision taken by the code, and then analyze what wrong assumptions lead to that decision.

Comment: You seem to be starting from the assumption that an optimal solution can be obtained by the approach you have taken but that you have made a coding error somewhere. If you truly want an optimal solution you have to first come up with an algorithm that can be proven to produce one. That I do not think one can do, because this is a very difficult problem (undoubtedly NP-Complete). Of course, you could enumerate all paths from start to finish, but that would be impractical for problems of any size...

Comment: @CarySwoveland Being or not being NP-complete has nothing to do with one's ability to prove an algorithm correct.

Comment: ...Perhaps you are not demanding an optimal solution but just want to get one that is in some sense "good". Such algorithms are called "heuristics". The problem with heuristics (with rare exceptions) is that there is no way of knowing how good they are, which makes them generally uninteresting on this forum. The rare exceptions are heuristics that produce a "best value" `X` and are able to determine a bound `B` such that `|O-X| <= B`, where `O` is the unknown optimal value. That does not apply here, however.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I am trying to think of an algorithm that has been proven to produce an optimal solution to a problem [known to be NP-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems), short of ones that enumerate all possibilities. Correct me if I am  wrong--a distinct possibility, as I have been out of that game for many moons.

Comment: There isn't one known, but this problem is not NP-complete, and is not hard by any stretch of imagination.

Comment: Perhaps before embarking on the search for a logic error, you want to *show* that 2 is the wrong answer here. Which path do you have in mind?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I invite you to offer an answer that presents an exact algorithm for this problem (with an arbitrary grid and arbitrary number of monsters). I am truly interested and I am sure others would be as well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Perhaps this question doesn't need an answer. OP says the algorithm is incorrect, but doesn't offer any evidence of that.

Comment: quantrader23, is this question just about your code or are you also interested in answers that suggest alternative ways of obtaining an optimal solution to your problem? If the latter I suggest you edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks look like my algorithm was all correct, just a minor issue of passing in the monster coordinates as a set of x coordinates and y coordinates (minor silly issue now that I think of it) separately as Trincot pointed out in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you pass the coordinates of the monsters as a set of x-coordinates and a set of y-coordinates. By defining them as sets, you:

- Cannot have two monsters in the same column, nor in the same row. Realise that `{3,4,3}` is the same set as `{3,4}`
- Cannot rely on the *order* of these coordinates, so that you risk to pair up unrelated coordinates.

The fix is to pass these coordinates as lists (as a side note: it would make more sense to pass a list of `(x, y)` tuples).

So if you alter your call to this:

```
print(findBestPath(5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 3, [0,0,3],[3,4,3]))
```

...the output will be 1, as would be the expected (since the target cell is a direct neighbor of a monster cell).

Comment: Ahh, this was it, a small but significant issue, appreciate it a lot :)